# Identity Server 4 responds with a 403 (forbidden) to Angular client on account/login

Tags: angular, .net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I am using Identity Server 4 (in .Net Core 2.2) with an Angular 9 client (using OidcSecurityService v11) - the setup is for the Angular client message to be routed to a remote ADFS server for authentication.

When the user arrives at the website https://client-staging.mydomain.com the user should be sent to the Identity Server (https://auth-staging.mydomain.com/account/login) then redirected off to the ADFS server's login page.

This is the way that it occurs in our *Development* environment.  In our *Staging* environment however the user arrives at the website (https://client-staging.mydomain.com) and is sent to the Identity Server (https://auth-staging.mydomain.com/account/login) but then the Identity Server responds with a 403 (Forbidden) immediately back to the client (i.e. doesn't redirect to the ADFS login page).  In the Staging environment (config is very similar to Development) the setup is as follows:

Angular client (OidcSecurityService) config

```
  oidcConfigService.withConfig({
    stsServer: "https://auth-staging.mydomain.com",
    redirectUrl: `${window.location.origin}/callback`,
    clientId: 'spaCodeClient',
    scope: 'openid profile MyWebProject',
    responseType: 'code',
    triggerAuthorizationResultEvent: true,
    postLogoutRedirectUri: `${window.location.origin}`,
    startCheckSession: false,
    silentRenew: true,
    silentRenewUrl: `${window.location.origin}/silent-renew.html`,
    postLoginRoute: '/disclaimer',
    forbiddenRoute: '/unauthorized',
    unauthorizedRoute: '/unauthorized',
    logLevel: LogLevel.Debug,
    historyCleanupOff: true,
    // iss_validation_off: false
    // disable_iat_offset_validation: true
    maxIdTokenIatOffsetAllowedInSeconds: 10,
    disableIatOffsetValidation: true
  });
```

Identity Server

```
"ADMetadataUrl": "https://fed.adfs-xxxx.com/federationmetadata/2007-06/federationmetadata.xml",
"ADRealm": "urn:idsrv3",
"SPAClientUrl": "https://client-staging.mydomain.com",
"Wtrealm": "https://auth-staging.mydomain.com/",

"Clients": [
  {
    "ClientId": "spaCodeClient",
    "ProtocolType": "oidc",
    "ClientSecrets": [],
    "RequireClientSecret": false,
    ...
    "RequireConsent": false,
    "AllowRememberConsent": true,
    "AllowedGrantTypes": [
      "authorization_code"
    ],
    "RequirePkce": true,
    "AllowPlainTextPkce": false,
    "AllowAccessTokensViaBrowser": true,
    "RedirectUris": [
      "https://client-staging.mydomain.com/callback",
      "https://client-staging.mydomain.com/silent-renew.html"
    ],
    "PostLogoutRedirectUris": [
      "https://client-staging.mydomain.com/unauthorized",
      "https://client-staging.mydomain.com"
    ],
    ...
    "AllowedCorsOrigins": [
      "https://client-staging.mydomain.com"
    ],
  }
]
```

Identity Server Startup.cs

```
ConfigureServices...
  ...
  services.AddIdentityServer()
      .AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
      .AddAspNetIdentity<ApplicationUser>()
      .AddInMemoryClients(Configuration.GetSection("IdentityServer:Clients"))
      .AddConfigurationStore(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDB"))
      .AddOperationalStore(Configuration.GetSection("CosmosDB"))
      .AddProfileService<ProfileService>(); 

  services.AddAuthentication()
      .AddWsFederation(options =>
      {
          options.MetadataAddress = Configuration.GetSection("ADMetadataUrl").Value;
          options.Wtrealm = Configuration.GetSection("Wtrealm").Value;
          //options.SaveTokens = true;
       });
  ...

Configure...
  ...
  app.UseIdentityServer();
  ....
```

Would anyone know why there would be a difference between our Development and Staging environments ?  The configs, websites, app-pools seem very similar

As a starting point would anyone know why the Angular client sending the Identity Server an /account/login request gets back the 403 when it should be redirecting to the ADFS server ?

**UPDATE 1**

Screenshot of browser|Network
[image: ADFS login screen shot]

Identity Server Logs

```
[00:46:48 INF] Policy execution successful.
[00:46:48 DBG] CORS request made for path: /.well-known/openid-configuration from origin: https://client-staging.mydomain.com
[00:46:48 DBG] Origin https://client-staging.mydomain.com is allowed: True
[00:46:48 DBG] CorsPolicyService allowed origin: https://client-staging.mydomain.com
[00:46:48 DBG] The request has an origin header: 'https://client-staging.mydomain.com'.
[00:46:48 INF] Policy execution successful.
[00:46:48 DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
[00:46:48 DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
[00:46:48 DBG] Request path /.well-known/openid-configuration matched to endpoint type Discovery
[00:46:48 DBG] Endpoint enabled: Discovery, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint
[00:46:48 INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.DiscoveryEndpoint for /.well-known/openid-configuration
[00:46:48 DBG] Start discovery request
[00:46:48 DBG] Found ["openid", "profile", "xxxxProjectNamexxxx"] as all scopes in database
[00:46:48 DBG] Connection id "0HM1JKEVESP2M" completed keep alive response.
[00:46:48 INF] Request finished in 22.9017ms 200 application/json; charset=UTF-8
[00:46:49 INF] Request starting HTTP/1.1 GET http://auth-staging.mydomain.com/connect/authorize?client_id=spaCodeClient&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fclient-staging.mydomain.com%2Fcallback&response_type=code&scope=openid%20profile%20xxxxProjectNamexxxx&nonce=cf60287293d9a0f804b932745919cedef1xbcdYkl&state=9189c5fbc6c2cc2f730bd4b94432d93439SGxEA1b&code_challenge=BKq8K854kgDrnGF3x8f4bvmkW-ooDldbR7eUkqzSADA&code_challenge_method=S256  
[00:46:49 DBG] The request path /connect/authorize does not match a supported file type
[00:46:49 DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
[00:46:49 DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
[00:46:49 DBG] Request path /connect/authorize matched to endpoint type Authorize
[00:46:49 DBG] Database URI: dbs/xxxxDbNamexxxx
[00:46:49 DBG] Database: {
  "id": "xxxxDbNamexxxx"
}
[00:46:49 DBG] Ensuring `xxxxDbNamexxxx` exists...
[00:46:49 DBG] xxxxDbNamexxxx Creation Results: OK
[00:46:49 DBG] Persisted Grants URI: dbs/xxxxDbNamexxxx/colls/PersistedGrants
[00:46:49 DBG] Persisted Grants Partition Key: {
  "paths": [
    "/clientId"
  ]
}
[00:46:49 DBG] Persisted Grants Indexing Policy: {
  "automatic": true,
  "indexingMode": "Consistent",
  "includedPaths": [
    {
      "path": "/*",
      "indexes": []
    }
  ],
  "excludedPaths": [],
  "compositeIndexes": [],
  "spatialIndexes": []
}
[00:46:49 DBG] Persisted Grants Unique Key Policy: {
  "uniqueKeys": [
    {
      "paths": [
        "/clientId",
        "/subjectId",
        "/type",
        "/key"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
[00:46:49 DBG] Persisted Grants Collection: {
  "id": "PersistedGrants",
  "partitionKey": {
    "paths": [
      "/clientId"
    ],
    "kind": "Hash"
  },
  "indexingPolicy": {
    "automatic": true,
    "indexingMode": "Consistent",
    "includedPaths": [
      {
        "path": "/*",
        "indexes": []
      }
    ],
    "excludedPaths": [],
    "compositeIndexes": [],
    "spatialIndexes": []
  },
  "uniqueKeyPolicy": {
    "uniqueKeys": [
      {
        "paths": [
          "/clientId",
          "/subjectId",
          "/type",
          "/key"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
[00:46:49 DBG] Persisted Grants Request Options: Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.RequestOptions
[00:46:49 DBG] Ensure Persisted Grants (ID:PersistedGrants) collection exists...
[00:46:49 DBG] PersistedGrants Creation Results: OK
[00:46:49 DBG] Endpoint enabled: Authorize, successfully created handler: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint
[00:46:49 INF] Invoking IdentityServer endpoint: IdentityServer4.Endpoints.AuthorizeEndpoint for /connect/authorize
[00:46:49 DBG] Start authorize request
[00:46:49 DBG] AuthenticationScheme: Identity.Application was not authenticated.
[00:46:49 DBG] No user present in authorize request
[00:46:49 DBG] Start authorize request protocol validation
[00:46:49 DBG] spaCodeClient found in database: True
[00:46:49 DBG] Checking for PKCE parameters
[00:46:49 DBG] Found ["openid", "profile"] identity scopes in database
[00:46:49 DBG] Found ["xxxxWebProjectxxxx"] API scopes in database
[00:46:49 DBG] Found ["openid", "profile"] identity scopes in database
[00:46:49 DBG] Found ["xxxxWebProjectxxxx"] API scopes in database
[00:46:49 DBG] Calling into custom validator: IdentityServer4.Validation.DefaultCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator
[00:46:49 INF] ValidatedAuthorizeRequest
{
  "ClientId": "spaCodeClient",
  "ClientName": "xxxxClientNamexxxx",
  "RedirectUri": "https://client-staging.mydomain/callback",
  "AllowedRedirectUris": [
    "https://client-staging.mydomain/callback",
    "https://client-staging.mydomain/silent-renew.html"
  ],
  "SubjectId": "anonymous",
  "ResponseType": "code",
  "ResponseMode": "query",
  "GrantType": "authorization_code",
  "RequestedScopes": "openid profile xxxxWebProjectxxx",
  "State": "9189c5fbc6c2cc2f730bd4b94432d93439SGxEA1b",
  "Nonce": "cf60287293d9a0f804b932745919cedef1xbcdYkl",
  "Raw": {
    "client_id": "spaCodeClient",
    "redirect_uri": "https://client-staging.mydomain.com/callback",
    "response_type": "code",
    "scope": "openid profile xxxxProjectNamexxxx",
    "nonce": "cf60287293d9a0f804b932745919cedef1xbcdYkl",
    "state": "9189c5fbc6c2cc2f730bd4b94432d93439SGxEA1b",
    "code_challenge": "BKq8K854kgDrnGF3x8f4bvmkW-ooDldbR7eUkqzSADA",
    "code_challenge_method": "S256"
  }
}
[00:46:49 INF] Showing login: User is not authenticated
```

**UPDATE 2**

It seems the 403 (Forbidden) behavior mentioned above (i.e. when the Angular client requests the login (/account/login) and gets back a 403 from the Identity Server) only occurs on external facing websites (i.e. locally and websites within the internal network get processed and sent off to the ADFS server as expected)

Comment: Can you attach Identity Server's logs?

Comment: Thanks for the reply - screenshot and logs added to post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This finished up being a trailing slash ('/') that was on the Identity Server config Wtrealm ("https://auth-staging.mydomain.com/") that was *not* on the OidcSecurityService config stsServer ("https://auth-staging.mydomain.com").  There doesn't seem to be any indication of this in the logs - really weird